# Azure - Cost management - virtual machines

Tags: azure

I'm looking for guidance on how to create a cost analysis report for Azure virtual machines. We did setup reservations, so some of the cost of the VM is being paid through a reservation, but other resources like disks, public IP, etc. are not.
How can I get a combined overview of the actual cost of a VM?

Ideally I can create a report that shows the cost per VM per month.

---

I've been trying to get the data with the REST API key, because I do believe that Roman his answer below does not contain all costs, and of course I did already check that in the Azure portal.

Here's my current script:

```
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId "..."

cls

# Get all enabled subscriptions in tenant
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription | ?{ $_.State -eq 'Enabled' }

# Set the year for which you want to get costs
$year = 2023

$buildResourceGroups = @("abc", "def", "ghi")

function Get-ConsumptionUsageDetail {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $subscriptionId,
      [Parameter(Mandatory)] [datetime] $beginDate,
      [Parameter(Mandatory)] [datetime] $endDate,
      [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $resourceGroupName
  )

  $resource = 'https://management.azure.com'
  $context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
  $accessToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, $resource).AccessToken
  
  $uriPath = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$($subscriptionId)/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails"

  # https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/manage-automation#get-usage-details-for-a-scope-during-specific-date-range
  #$uriQuery = '?startDate=' + $beginDate + '&endDate=' + $endDate + '&$filter=properties/resourceGroup eq ' + $resourceGroupName + '&api-version=2023-05-01'
  $uriQuery = '?startDate=' + $beginDate + '&endDate=' + $endDate + '&$filter={properties/resourceGroup eq ' + $resourceGroupName + '}&api-version=2023-05-01'

  $uri = $uriPath + $uriQuery
  $uri
  $consumptionDetailsRaw = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $uri -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer " + $accessToken }

  $consumptionDetails = @()
  foreach ($detail in $consumptionDetailsRaw.value) {
    $convertedDetail = @{
      SubscriptionGuid  = $detail.properties.subscriptionGuid
      InstanceName      = ($detail.properties.instanceName -split '/')[-1]
      AccountName       = $detail.properties.billingAccountName
      DepartmentName    = $detail.properties.billingProfileName
      CostCenter        = $detail.properties.costCenter
      BillingPeriodName = $detail.properties.billingPeriodStartDate
      UsageStart        = $detail.properties.date
      UsageEnd          = $detail.properties.date
      ConsumedService   = $detail.properties.consumedService
      Product           = $detail.properties.product
      Currency          = $detail.properties.billingCurrencyCode
      MeterDetails      = @{
        MeterName        = $detail.properties.meterDetails.meterName
        MeterCategory    = $detail.properties.meterDetails.meterCategory
        MeterSubCategory = $detail.properties.meterDetails.meterSubCategory
        Unit             = $detail.properties.meterDetails.unitOfMeasure
        MeterLocation    = $detail.properties.resourceLocation
      }
      UsageQuantity     = $detail.properties.quantity
      PreTaxCost        = $detail.properties.costInUSD
    }

    $consumptionDetails += $convertedDetail
  }

  return $consumptionDetails
}

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    Write-Host "`nChecking billing for '$($subscription.Name)' subscription."
    Set-AzContext -Subscription "$($subscription.Name)"

    foreach ($resourceGroupName in $buildResourceGroups) {
        $resourceGroup = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        if ($resourceGroup) {
            Write-Host "Resource group '$resourceGroupName' exists in '$($subscription.Name)' subscription." -ForegroundColor Green

            #$billingPeriods = Get-AzBillingPeriod | Where { $_.Name -like "$year*" }
            $billingPeriods = Get-AzBillingPeriod | Where { $_.Name -like "202311*" }

            foreach ($bp in $billingPeriods) {
                Write-Host "Checking billing period: $($bp.Name)"
                Write-Host "This billing periode has start date '$($bp.BillingPeriodStartDate)' and end date '$($bp.BillingPeriodEndDate)'."

                $consumptionDetails = Get-ConsumptionUsageDetail -subscriptionId $($subscription.Id) -beginDate $bp.BillingPeriodStartDate -endDate $bp.BillingPeriodEndDate -resourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
                $consumptionDetails | Format-Table
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Resource group '$resourceGroupName' does not exist in '$($subscription.Name)' subscription."
        }
    }

    Write-Host "`n----------------------------------------------`n"
}
```

Current issue is that my filter is not working, it outputs everything from that subscription instead of only the cost for that resource group.

Comment: This answers why the filter for "Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails" isn't working.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/23510

Comment: Apparently, in the new way, we can't filter yet on ResourceGroupName...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/generate-cost-details-report/create-operation?view=rest-cost-management-2023-11-01&tabs=HTTP#uri-parameters

Answer (score 0):

1. Azure Cost Management.
2. Resource group -> cost analysis

If you want to see price only for VMs, just move them to separately resource group and use the cost analysis tool for it.

Comment: Does this overview also include the price paid for the reservations?

Comment: I guess in the forecast option you should see this info

Comment: You guess? I need to know based on documentation or something please ;)